# why does <xsl:apply-templates select="//z:row" mode="Items" /> returns empty but <xsl:copy-of select="//z:row" /> returns a node set?

Tags: xml, xslt

Input XML
The input XML has those nested NewDataSet/Contracts nodes because it is being generated by a series of "recursive" transformations. This is what I have to work with.

```
<NewDataSet>
    <Contracts>
        <NewDataSet>
            <Contracts>
                <NewDataSet>
                    <Contracts>
                        <NewDataSet>
                            <Contracts>
                                <listitems xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
                                    <rs:data xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" ItemCount="6">
                                        <z:row xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" ows_BPID="VCT-00139" ows_Title="Contract - Joe Owner Jane Co-Owner" ows_PerformanceStart="2021-07-05T20:09:07Z" ows_PerformanceEnd="2023-03-27T20:09:07Z"/>
                                        <z:row xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" ows_BPID="VCT-00138" ows_Title="Contract - Jane Owner Joe Co-Owner" ows_PerformanceStart="2021-05-06T20:07:57Z" ows_PerformanceEnd="2022-04-01T20:07:57Z"/>
                                    </rs:data>
                                </listitems>
                            </Contracts>
                        </NewDataSet>
                    </Contracts>
                </NewDataSet>
            </Contracts>
        </NewDataSet>
    </Contracts>
</NewDataSet>
```

**StyleSheet #1**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" xmlns:cw="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" >
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Items xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//z:row" mode="Items" />
        </Items>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="Items">
        <Item>
            <xsl:attribute name='ows_Title' >
                <xsl:value-of select="@ows_Title"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </Item>     
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**StyleSheet #2**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" xmlns:cw="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" >
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Items xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
            <xsl:copy-of select="//z:row" />
        </Items>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="Items">
        <Item>
            <xsl:attribute name='ows_Title' >
                <xsl:value-of select="@ows_Title"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </Item>     
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**StyleSheet #3**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" xmlns:cw="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" >
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Items xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//z:row" mode="Items" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="//z:row" />
        </Items>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="Items">
        <Item>
            <xsl:attribute name='ows_Title' >
                <xsl:value-of select="@ows_Title"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </Item>     
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I apply StyleSheet #1, I get an empty response.

When I apply StyleSheet #2, I get

```
<Items>
<z:row xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" ows_BPID="VCT-00139" ows_Title="Contract - Joe Owner Jane Co-Owner" ows_PerformanceStart="2021-07-05T20:09:07Z" ows_PerformanceEnd="2023-03-27T20:09:07Z"/>
<z:row xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" ows_BPID="VCT-00138" ows_Title="Contract - Jane Owner Joe Co-Owner" ows_PerformanceStart="2021-05-06T20:07:57Z" ows_PerformanceEnd="2022-04-01T20:07:57Z"/>
</Items>
```

When I apply StyleSheet #3, I get

```
<Items>
    <Item ows_Title="Contract - Joe Owner Jane Co-Owner" />
    <Item ows_Title="Contract - Jane Owner Joe Co-Owner" />
    <z:row xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" ows_BPID="VCT-00139" ows_Title="Contract - Joe Owner Jane Co-Owner" ows_PerformanceStart="2021-07-05T20:09:07Z" ows_PerformanceEnd="2023-03-27T20:09:07Z"/>
    <z:row xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" ows_BPID="VCT-00138" ows_Title="Contract - Jane Owner Joe Co-Owner" ows_PerformanceStart="2021-05-06T20:07:57Z" ows_PerformanceEnd="2022-04-01T20:07:57Z"/>
</Items>
```

But, what I really want is

```
<Items>
    <Item ows_Title="Contract - Joe Owner Jane Co-Owner" />
    <Item ows_Title="Contract - Jane Owner Joe Co-Owner" />
</Items>
```

I don't know enough XML/XSLT to understand this behavior. Why does apply-templates returns nothing as if select="//z:row" were empty yet copy-of returns exactly the content as I expect it?

How do I get the result I want?

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"When I apply StyleSheet #1, I get an empty response."* I see a different result: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtEt

Comment: Yes, I see. you get the intended result which is good news for my XSLT but terrible for actually solving my problem because no one will be able to replicate it.  smh.  Thanks

Comment: Double check any namespaces used, any white space or spelling difference between input and XSLT might explain why the apply-templates selects nothing. Also, which XSLT processor do you use? Have you tried to run your failing code through a different processor?

Comment: I would expect all these stylesheet to produce an `Items` element that contains multiple namespace declarations. If there aren't any, then there's something very odd about your XSLT processor.

Comment: Using Saxon 9.1.J and applying your first transformation, I get exavtly the result you wanted. You are obviously using a buggy XSLT processor. Even using a compliant XSLT 1.0 processor, such as MSXML 4.0 or Saxon 6.5.3 also produces the same, wanted result.

Comment: I believe that the issue is not with the XML or XSLT but rather with how the application that invokes the XSLT Processor (some version of Saxon) is handling the documents.
I will keep investigating and post what I find.
Thanks everyone.